# Rules Compliance Metric Sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.6

The Rules Compliance metric for Sonarqube 5.6 is missing. The Issues Density plugin is deprecated as well as Violation Density so I am not sure what to do now.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Rules Compliance was deprecated in 4.0 and gone by 4.5.

You should instead be focusing on The Leak, i.e. the new problems introduced since the application's last version.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new **Rules Compliance Plugin** available in later versions (SQ 5.6+). Note that the metric has changed name (to *rules_compliance_index* and *rules_compliance_rating*) so any web service integration will have to take that into account.

https://github.com/willemsrb/sonar-rci-plugin (also available through the SonarQube update center)